# iOS View Controller size is 4 inch on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have iPhone oriented application, the UI created using a storyboard, when I run it on 4.7 or 5.5 inch devices it presented as 4 inch screen with black empty space on top and bottom of window.
The project was created on Xcode 6 and I got the issue when I compile it with Xcode 7 but I'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: You need to add splash screen for both 4.7 and 5.5 inch. After adding splash screen you will get exact height and width for you viewcontroller.

Comment: I totally agree with @V.J .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Xcode 7 you must add the launch screens (on "images.xcassets") of your desired resolution (iphone6 , iphone5...) or instead you can add the splash screen that automatically will work for all resolutions (YourProjectName/General/App Icons and Launch Images).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found that splash screen view controller was not set, just adding new one fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't add added **Launch Images** with proper resolution in proper place. So your app is considering it only for **iphone5 not above** so.Place **launch Images properly**.It will help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are [Apple's answers](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5572):

> If you don't use launch images, but you do have a Launch Screen (nib
>   or storyboard) then we synthesize your launch screen at install time.
>
> If you don't have any launch images, and you don't have a launch nib
>   or storyboard, then you are declaring that you don't support any
>   screen sizes aside from 320x480
>
> A brand new project should not demonstrate any of these issues
>
> With the iPad Pro you will need a Launch Screen to support the new
>   screen size (and you need Launch Screens to support multitasking on
>   iPad in general).